# unknown attribute 'development_id' for Lot with cocoon triple nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm almost certain I know what the problem is, and if I'm correct, I just can't find where the problem is lying.

When triple-nesting with the cocoon gem, I'm having what seems to be an error with incorrect pluralisation. I have 3 resources, `Developments` > `Lots` > `Listings`, where Developments is the grandparent, Lots is the parent and Listings is the child.

The error I'm getting is `unknown attribute 'development_id' for Lot.` stemming from `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in Developments#new`. I've checked my models and partials and have been playing around with them. Here is my code:

## developments_controller.rb

```
class DevelopmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_development, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /developments or /developments.json
  def index
    @developments = Development.all
  end

  # GET /developments/1 or /developments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /developments/new
  def new
    @development = Development.new
  end

  # GET /developments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /developments or /developments.json
  def create
    @development = Development.new(development_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @development.save
        format.html { redirect_to @development, notice: "Development was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @development }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @development.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /developments/1 or /developments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @development.update(development_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @development, notice: "Development was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @development }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @development.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /developments/1 or /developments/1.json
  def destroy
    @development.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to developments_url, notice: "Development was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_development
      @development = Development.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def development_params
      params.require(:development).permit(:development_name, :development_type, :development_address, :description, :estimated_completion_date, :body_corp,
       lots_attributes: [:id, :status, :stage, :land_size, :price, :eta, :_destroy, 
        listings_attributes: [:id, :lot_number, :price, :type, :bed, :bath, :car, :house_size, :rent, :_destroy]])
    end
end
```

## development.rb (model)

```
class Development < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lots
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :lots, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: :true
end
```

## Lot.rb (model)

```
class Lot < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :listings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :listings, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: :true
  belongs_to :development
end
```

## Listing.rb (model)

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lot
  end
```

## _form.html.erb (partial)

```
<%= form_for @development do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :development_name%>
    <%= f.text_field :development_name%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :development_type %>
    <%= f.text_field :development_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :development_address %>
    <%= f.text_field :development_address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :estimated_completion_date %>
    <%= f.date_select :estimated_completion_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body_corp %>
    <%= f.number_field :body_corp %>
  </div>
  <div id="listings">
    <%= f.fields_for :lots do |lot| %>
      <%= render 'lot_fields', f: lot %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add lot', f, :lots %>
    </div>
  </div>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

## _lot_fields.html.erb (partial)

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <h3> New Lots </h3>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stage %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :stage %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :land_size %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :land_size %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :eta %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :eta %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove lot", f %>
</div>
```

## _listing_fields.html.erb (partial)

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <h3> New Listing </h3>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stage %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :stage %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :land_size %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :land_size %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :eta %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :eta %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove listing", f %>
</div>
```

## new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Development</h1>

<%= render 'form', development: @development %>

<%= link_to 'Back', developments_path %>
```

I have a clone project of this and I noticed in the `schema.rb` that there is a key difference:

```
t.index ["developments_id"], name: "index_lots_on_developments_id"
```

I believe it should be `development_id` instead of being pluralised, but I'm not sure where/how this needs to be changed. I'm under the impression you should never alter a schema file.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, it should be :
`t.index ["development_id"], name: "index_lots_on_development_id"`

You have to rewrite a migration with

```
def change
  remove_index :lots, name: "index_lots_on_developments_id"
  add_reference :lots, :development, index: true
end
```